# How to use Dictionary (like iphone NSDictionary) in android?

Tags: android, keymapping

I have worked in soap message, and to parse the value from Webservice, the values are stored in ArrayList.

Example: 
values are Employee name (Siva) and Employee id (3433fd), these two values are stored in arraylist, but I want to stored in Dictionary, How?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

you can use HashMap like this

```
Map <String,String> map =  new HashMap<String,String>();
//add items 
map.put("3433fd","Siva");
//get items 

String employeeName =(String) map.get("3433fd");
```

Comment: is that what you are looking for?

Comment: these is also like (iPhone Dictionary)

Comment: I believe the map object method for adding key value pairs is 'put', not 'add'

Answer (score 11):

You can use [Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html).

as it offers String to various types of Mapping.

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putInt("identifier", 121);
b.putString("identifier", "Any String");
b.putStringArray("identifier", stringArray);

int i = b.getInt("identifier");
...
```

Comment: Thanks. A lot of answers point to hash map but actually I think bundle is more similar to dictionary because it allows more types of variables

Answer (score 6):

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        EditText textview = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextHash);
        EditText textviewNew = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextHash2);

        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
        map.put("iOS", "100");
        map.put("Android", "101");
        map.put("Java", "102");
        map.put(".Net", "103");

        String TextString = "";
       // Set<E> keys = map.keySet();

       Set keys = map.keySet();
       System.out.println("keys "+keys);
        for (Iterator i = keys.iterator(); i.hasNext();) 
        {
            String key = (String) i.next();
            System.out.println("key "+key);
            String value = (String) map.get(key);
            System.out.println("value "+value);
            textview.append(key + " = " + value);
            TextString+=(key + " = " + value); 
        }
        //textviewNew.setText(TextString);

//        Iterator iterator = map.keySet().iterator();
//        
//        while (iterator.hasNext()) 
//        {
//          String object = (String) iterator.next();
//          textview.setText(object);
//      }
//        
//        //textview.setText(map.get("Siva"));
//        
//        System.out.println(map);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A [Dictionary](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Dictionary.html) is an abstract class that maps keys to values and there is Dictionary Class in android refer [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Dictionary.html) you can find a note at Class Overview

> Do not use this class since it is obsolete. Please use the Map
>   interface for new implementations.

An attempt to insert either a null key or a null value to a dictionary will result to a [NullPointerException](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/NullPointerException.html),but you can use [Map](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Map.html) interface,it  provides the exact same functionality of a dictionary.you can use it as bellow

```
//put values
Map Message = new HashMap();
Message.put("title", "Test message");
Message.put("description", "message description");
Message.put("email", "email@gmail.com");
//get values
Log.d("get Message","Message title -"+Message.get("title"));
```

you can also use A custom class as below

```
public class MessageObject {
    String title;
    String description;
    String email;
}
```

you can use Getters and Setters to get and put values,not needed to remember the key names every time you may get some other advantages by this way.